# Download OpenStreetMap style sheet or mss file

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, mapbox

I have download a shapefile from OpenStreetMap (OSM), then I open it using TileMill.  The next step is create stylesheet ".mss" file.

How can I download the exact OSM's stylesheet?

Comment: Same question exist on [openstreetmap-help](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/15875/how-to-output-from-tilemill-in-a-format-like-openstreetmaporg-standard)

Answer (score 3):

The OSM stylesheet is on github :
https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto

Comment: The question was how to download the MSS file, so giving a link to the project is fine.

Answer (score 1):

OSM uses (-ed) the native Mapnik XML stylesheets, while Tilemill uses CartoCSS as style language. You need to get a converted map style file here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/CartoCSS